# Can you please identify this beetle?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology

Can you please identify this species of beetle? It was about 2 cm (or 0,8 inches) in size. Photo is from Greece, Europe.

[image]

Comment: Could you please add the (estimated) size of this beetle?

Comment: about 2 cm ,  0,8 inches.

Comment: It looks a bit like a [*Phyllopertha horticola*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phyllopertha_horticola) (Garden Chafer, from Scarabaeidae), with the antenna hidden, but 2 cm is too large. It could be a related Scarab beelte though, or you are overestimating the size (which is common with insects, when you dont actually measure them). The picture is a bit dark to judge though.

Comment: Definitely a scarab, likely Subfamily Cetoniinae. You should post an answer @fileunderwater

Answer (score 1):

The insect in the Photo is a beetle (order Coleoptera), in the scarab family (family Scarabaeidae). It is most likely in the Genus Phyllophaga (June or May bugs) or Phyllopertha (garden chafers).  Beetles such as this are commonly referred to as "Chafers" feeding on plant leaves and flowers during the day. One of the defining characteristics in the photo is the apparent "Hairiness" (setae) visible at the sides of the insect body. I am inclined to agree with the good observations expressed in the comments.  It likely to be a garden chafer Phyllopertha horticola. Some helpful links are below.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phyllopertha_horticola

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phyllophaga

https://www.flickr.com/photos/72271115@N02/galleries/72157651475342046/?rb=1#photo_14184003066

https://www.flickr.com/photos/odonataman/14184003066/in/gallery-72271115@N02-72157651475342046/

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scarabaeidae